# One QWebEnginePage for two or more QWebEngineView

Tags: c++, qt, qtwebengine

I have one instance of QWebEnginePage that is loaded with some url (e.g. https://www.google.com)

I want this page to be displayed in two QWebEngineViews, but it looks like Qt doesn't allow that.

Once I call setPage on one view, the other view stops rendering the page.
Looks like it is a matter of ownership or something like that, but I don't see any information about that in Qt docs.

Anyone else faced such issue?

```
auto p = new QWebEnginePage();
p->load(QUrl("https://www.google.com"));

auto w1 = new QWebEngineView();
auto w2 = new QWebEngineView();

w1->setPage(p);
w2->setPage(p);

w1->show();
w2->show();
```

I expect both views to display the same page, but only w2 shows it. If you later call `w1->setPage(p)` - the page will be displayed on w1 and will disappear from w2.

UPD.
Just want to post the conclusion.
- the QWebEnginePage's view() method proofs one-one-one relationship.
- setPage source code clearly shows that "Second time it just disconnects from the first view."
- "If the current page is a child of the web view, it will be deleted." - doesn't answer my question at all. My pages are not children of the web view and are not deleted, just not being rendered both at a time as I expected.

Comment: You are right, I've updated my answer with related piece of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QWebEnginePage` can't be connected to two `QWebEngineView`s.

You  will easily understand what happens when you are calling `setPage` twice when you will look at [Qt sources](https://github.com/RSATom/Qt/blob/master/qtwebengine/src/webenginewidgets/api/qwebengineview.cpp), see `setPage` function there. Second time it just disconnects from the first view.

```
void QWebEngineView::setPage(QWebEnginePage* page)
{
    QWebEngineViewPrivate::bind(this, page);
}

void QWebEngineViewPrivate::bind(QWebEngineView *view, QWebEnginePage *page)
{
    if (view && page == view->d_func()->page)
        return;

    if (page) {
        // Un-bind page from its current view.
        if (QWebEngineView *oldView = page->d_func()->view) {
            page->disconnect(oldView);
            oldView->d_func()->page = 0;
        }
        page->d_func()->view = view;
        page->d_func()->adapter->reattachRWHV();
    }

    if (view) {
        // Un-bind view from its current page.
        if (QWebEnginePage *oldPage = view->d_func()->page) {
            oldPage->disconnect(view);
            oldPage->d_func()->view = 0;
            oldPage->d_func()->adapter->reattachRWHV();
            if (oldPage->parent() == view)
                delete oldPage;
        }
        view->d_func()->page = page;
    }

    // skipped
}
```

Comment: @Joe when he is calling setPage for the second time, page is unbinding from the the first view. Any way, it is necessary to create two instances of page to make this work

Comment: Yes, but that quote isn't related to that fact.

Comment: @Joe, agree - I removed bad quote and added piece of code which explains what happens during setPage()

Answer (score 0):

`QWebEnginePage` has a method `QWebEnginePage::view` that returns a pointer to the `QWidget` currently showing the page. Therefore, it can by definition only have a single view, despite the fact that the view doesn't take ownership of the page (where ownership is always a one to one relationship)

I would suggest creating two `QWebEnginePage` instances and connecting the signals to their respective slots (or lambdas which call a corresponding non-slot setter) of the other page. Some like `scrollPositionChanged` might not have corresponding setters, so you might be out of luck for perfect synchronization.

Comment: Never used that QWebEnginePage::view method, but yes - this method proves one-to-one relationship. However, the setPage method documentation http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineview.html#setPage says that View does not take the ownership of the page - thus I thought it might be shared across views.